# Telethon: Use same session_string at once

Tags: telegram, telethon

I have my client online (answer to user messages), but also I have mailer that sends news sometimes.

Because of that at some point of time there is two clients with same session string at once.

It seems like first (main) client stops working after second (mailer) sends some messages with session string.

How to fix that? Is it possible to use same session_string at the same time in two clients?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegram doesn't like it when you use the same session from multiple places. The correct approach would be to login two separate times and thus maintain two separate sessions for the same account.